# Python fails to find path which exists in windows

Tags: python-3.x, escaping, listdir

I have this python code:

```
import os
import shutil

# Function to get the total size of a directory including subdirectories
def get_directory_size(path):
    total_size = 0
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for filename in filenames:
            filepath = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
            total_size += os.path.getsize(filepath)
    return total_size

# Function to list pip.log files bigger than 0.1 GB with their sizes
def list_large_pip_log_files_with_size(path, size_threshold):
    large_pip_log_files = []
    try:
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
            for filename in filenames:
                if filename == "pip.log":
                    filepath = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                    file_size = os.path.getsize(filepath)
                    if file_size > size_threshold:  # 0.1 GB in bytes
                        large_pip_log_files.append((filepath, file_size))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
    return large_pip_log_files

# Function to list first-level subdirectories bigger than 0.1 GB with their sizes
def list_large_first_level_subdirectories_with_size(path, size_threshold):
    large_subdirectories = []
    try:
        for dirname in os.listdir(path):
            dir_full_path = os.path.join(path, dirname)
            if os.path.isdir(dir_full_path):
                dir_size = get_directory_size(dir_full_path)
                if dir_size > size_threshold:  # 0.1 GB in bytes
                    large_subdirectories.append((dir_full_path, dir_size))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
    return large_subdirectories

# Function to delete selected files/directories
def delete_items(items_to_delete):
    deleted_size = 0
    for item_path, item_size in items_to_delete:
        try:
            if os.path.isfile(item_path):
                os.remove(item_path)
            elif os.path.isdir(item_path):
                shutil.rmtree(item_path)
            deleted_size += item_size
            print(f"Deleted: {item_path} ({item_size / (1024 * 1024 * 1024):.2f} GB)")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error deleting {item_path}: {str(e)}")
    return deleted_size

# Input paths
pip_log_path = "C:/your_pip_log_directory"
subdirectories_paths = [
    "C:/subdirectory_path1",
    "C:/subdirectory_path2",
    # Add more paths as needed
]

# File size threshold (0.1 GB)
size_threshold = 0.1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024  # 0.1 GB in bytes

# Check if it's a dry run
dry_run = input("Is this a dry run? (y/n): ").strip().lower() == "y"

# List large pip.log files
large_pip_log_files = list_large_pip_log_files_with_size(pip_log_path, size_threshold)

# List large first-level subdirectories
large_first_level_subdirectories = []
for path in subdirectories_paths:
    large_first_level_subdirectories.extend(list_large_first_level_subdirectories_with_size(path, size_threshold))

# Combine and sort the lists by size in descending order
all_large_items = large_pip_log_files + large_first_level_subdirectories
all_large_items.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

# Display the list to the user
print("Large pip.log Files and First-Level Subdirectories to Delete:")
for i, (item_path, item_size) in enumerate(all_large_items):
    print(f"{i+1}: {item_path} ({item_size / (1024 * 1024 * 1024):.2f} GB)")

# Ask the user for items to delete
if not dry_run:
    user_input = input("Enter numbers of items to delete (separated by space), or 0 to exit: ")
    items_to_delete_indices = [int(i) - 1 for i in user_input.split() if i.isnumeric()]
```

I have problem when I'm trying to pass this path: `r'F:\temp\.clone - sb'`

when it reaches this code:

`for dirname in os.listdir(path):`

is throw `FileNotFoundError` exception. The folder exists for sure and I'm able to get there and its sub directories.

I tried few escape chars, but nothing helped. any idea?

BTW, I debugged the code, and this is what python sees: `'F:\\temp\\.clone - sb'`

Comment: Try going into `'F:\\temp\\.clone - sb'` open a python interpreter there and try `os. getcwd()` or create a file there and try use `os.path.dirname()` on it or something like that, see what the output is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. I opened project from this path, and I saw that python reads it as: `F:\temp\.clone-sb` . It turns out python remove by himself the spaces. So after updating the path in my code for that, it worked like charm